# How can I Import Exported Chrome bookmarks and REPLACE existing bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7

I had two different devices somehow not sync'ing chrome bookmarks for a whilie.

And then when I sync'd I ended up with lots of duplicates.

I did do a Bookmark Manager > Export before syncing. However, when I Import those it just makes yet another copy of those bookmarks (now I have even more duplicates).

Is there a way to erase the existing bookmarks and then import the exported chrome bookmarks?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to uninstall chrome. Just go into the Bookmarks manager, select the first bookmark, and use shift when selecting the the last bookmark to highlight them all, then hit delete on your keyboard. Import the new file.

Comment: Thanks! Another way to select all: Bookmarks manager -> CTRL+A

Answer (score 2):

1. Export bookmarks from the other device where you use Chrome to an HTML file.
2. Uninstall Google Chrome and reinstall Google Chrome on the device where you will import bookmarks from the HTML file that you saved. Alternatively uncheck *Bookmarks* in Chrome's *Settings* -> *Advanced sync settings* and delete all of the Google Chrome bookmarks on the device where you will import bookmarks from the HTML file that you saved.
3. Import bookmarks to the newly installed Chrome from the HTML file that you saved. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu **⋮** -> *Bookmarks* -> *Import
   bookmarks and settings…* -> from the dropdown menu under *Import
   bookmarks and settings* select *Bookmarks HTML File* -> under
   *Select items to import:* review the checkboxes and uncheck the checkboxes next to the items that you don't want to import  -> click
   *Choose File* button. Browse to the HTML file that you saved and select it.

   [image]
4. The Chrome bookmarks have to be in the same order on both devices in order to sync properly. In the top-right corner of the browser  window, click the Chrome menu **⋮** -> *Bookmarks* -> *Bookmark Manager*. From the open *Bookmark Manager* tab in Chrome rearrange the bookmark folders by dragging them until they are in the same order on both devices.